# Audio not working with Phillips SHB5500 Bluetooth headset

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones

Hello fellow Ubuntuners!

I have recently purchased said headset and went through the very simple process of pairing my computer with it. Although I managed to pair the headset with the computer I was unable to make the sweet sound flow through the headset.

Unfortunate.

I suppose I was expecting an option in the sound menu to switch the "Play sound through" option from my onboard speakers to the headset but, alas, it was not to be. An option in the sound menu, that is. It wasn't there.
So, any idea about what I should do to make it work? any information I might be able to provide to assist with the solving of said issue?
Thanks!

Edit:
 pactl list short | grep -i bluetooth showed:

7   module-bluetooth-policy
8   module-bluetooth-discover

Comment: Edit your question to include terminal results for `pactl list short | grep -i bluetooth` Thanks

Comment: Now edited! Any help would be appreciated.